# Compilation errors when writing a quadratic formula program

Tags: c++, math

Can't get this code to compile and work properly

The implementation file:

```
#include <cmath>
#include "quadEquation.h"
using namespace std;

QuadEquation::QuadEquation()
{
  int a,b,c;
}

QuadEquation::QuadEquation(int first, int second, int third)
{
  a = first;
  b = second;
  c = third;
}

int QuadEquation::getA()
{
  return a;
}
int QuadEquation::getB()
{
  return b;
}
int QuadEquation::getC()
{
  return c;
}
int QuadEquation::getDiscriminant()
{
  return b * b - 4 * a * c;
}
int QuadEquation::getRoot1()
{
  discrim = getDiscrimant();
  return -b + sqrt(discrim) / (2 * a);
}
int QuadEquation::getRoot2()
{
  discrim = getDiscriminant();
  return -b - sqrt(discrim) / (2 * a);
}
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef QUADEQUATION_H
#define QUADEQUATION_H

class QuadEquation
{
 private:
  int a, b, c;

 public:
  QuadEquation(int, int, int);
  int getA();
  int getB();
  int getC();
  int getDiscriminant();
  int getRoot1();
  int getRoot2();
};

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include "quadEquation.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  QuadEquation quad1(1,0,9);
  cout << "The first root  of the first quadratic equation is: " << quad1.getRoot1() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Some errors that i am getting

```
quadEquation.cpp:5: error: prototype for ‘QuadEquation::QuadEquation()’ does not match any in class `QuadEquation`
quadEquation.h:5: error: candidates are: `QuadEquation::QuadEquation(const QuadEquation&)`
quadEquation.h:10: error:                `QuadEquation::QuadEquation(int, int, int)`
quadEquation.cpp: In member function `int QuadEquation::getRoot1()`:
quadEquation.cpp:35: error: `discrim` was not declared in this scope
quadEquation.cpp:35: error: `getDiscrimant` was not declared in this scope
quadEquation.cpp: In member function `int QuadEquation::getRoot2()`:
quadEquation.cpp:40: error: `discrim` was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Just for reference, here's the idiomatic (i.e. "expert style") version of your class: http://ideone.com/qEigx

Answer (score 1):

One of the constructors you've defined is

```
QuadEquation::QuadEquation()
{
  int a,b,c;
}
```

But this constructor isn't defined in your header file.  Moreover, it looks like this is an error on your part, since this constructor doesn't make much sense - it just declares three local variables and doesn't use any of them.  If you do want to declare this constructor, add it to your header file, but judging from your code I don't believe it's necessary.

As to your other errors, look at this code:

```
int QuadEquation::getRoot1()
{
  discrim = getDiscrimant();
  return -b + sqrt(discrim) / (2 * a);
}
```

Two things jump out at me.  First, where is `discrim` declared?  Second, if quadratic formulas can have arbitrary complex-valued roots, is there a reason you're returning an `int`?  Is there a different type you could use here instead?

Overall, you should learn to read these compiler error messages.  Everything I've pointed out could easily have been gleaned from the error output.  Now that you're aware what the problems are, can you see how they generate the given compiler errors?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Moreover, quadratic equations can have arbitrary complex solutions.

Comment: no reason for returning int other than this is just practice coding.

Comment: Now its saying getDiscriminant was not declared in this scope in QuadEquation::getRoot1()???

Comment: @Sean- I'm going to let you figure this out on your own.  You should learn how to read compiler error messages.  It's an absolutely essential skill, and this is a very run-of-the-mill error message.

Comment: @Sean: No, it doesn't say `getDiscriminant` was not declared.  It says `getDiscrimant` was not declared.  Don't retype error messages, use copy+paste.